# Enable user to allow notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement user notifications in flutter/firebase/android.

I added the function requestPermission()

```
class NavigatorView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigatorView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavigatorViewState createState() => _NavigatorViewState();
}

class _NavigatorViewState extends State<NavigatorView> {
  String get userId => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.id;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestPermission();
  }

  requestPermission() async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      log('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      log('User grander provisional permission');
    } else {
      log('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }
  }

  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    //HomePage(),
    const AllMyChats(),
    const JobApplicationsView(),
    const JobFilter(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 10,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Chats',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Jobs',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Job Applications',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but it never asks for permission. I always see the following log:

> User declined or has not accepted permission

what am I missing here?

Comment: asking notification permission is applicable only to ios, for android, the permission is based on user phone settings.

Comment: ur my hero! thank you!  ... adding u on linkedin!

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue recently on Android. You need to modify the build for for gradle to target sdk 33 and to compile sdk 33 if you are using a newer phone or emulator. The older SDKs do not have the notification permission included with them so by updating the compile or target sdk to a higher value, you should enable the permission dialog box for your end users.